# Pull stories data from instagram graph basic api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I created new app with instagram basic display.
I managed to get all media data from the instagram users after they use my authentication mechanism that would retrieve and stored access token.

This is an endpoint that works really well and fetch all media data:
[https://graph.instagram.com/{{api-version}}/{{user-id}}/media?access_token={{access-token}}&fields=caption,id,is_shared_to_feed,media_type,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username,children](https://graph.instagram.com/%7B%7Bapi-version%7D%7D/%7B%7Buser-id%7D%7D/media?access_token=%7B%7Baccess-token%7D%7D&fields=caption,id,is_shared_to_feed,media_type,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username,children)

I am slightly worried that I would have to create brand new app to display stories and that would require business account.

I think that is the only way to go now, but it's shame that I cannot use basic instagram api to display stories, unless someone managed to get it working.